# Configure exim in debian 6

Tags: email, debian-squeeze, exim

I am trying to configure exim with gmail in my debian 6 system as per this tutorial http://www.manu-j.com/blog/wordpress-exim4-ubuntu-gmail-smtp/75/.After configuring,

When i run `update-exim4.conf` i am getting this message,

```
Exim configuration error:
  two client authenticators (gmail_login and login) have the same public name (LOGIN)
Invalid new configfile /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp, not installing 
/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp to /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
```

Any pointers to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if you already solved this one but I just used the guide you're linking and got it to work.

The error you're getting is because you didn't remove the default login section from your `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`.

Look for a line with the following: `public_name = LOGIN`, some lines above that you'll find a section named `login:` you should erase that whole section and try again.